# How to change non-consumable to auto-renewable subscriptions and keep old user?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store

I've had in-app purchase feature with non-consumable pricing in Apple Store. And the app has pricing to use it.

How to change non-consumable to auto-renewable subscriptions? Somehow keep user who purchased the app. And new user charge with auto-renewable subscriptions.

Comment: does Apple allow your app update? I worry this will violate the review guideline.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't change it, just make sure in your App, you use
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]restoreCompletedTransactions];

Restore old purchase and check if you find that the user has purchased the non-consumable product (old users), restore the product for free. If user has not purchased that product before (new users), ask them to purchase the new auto-renewable subscriptions.